# How can I detect WHY an image failed to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, onerror

I've got an img element on a page with its src being set dynamically on page load (different images for different situations, and the images are provided by clients).

I can detect WHEN an image fails to load and I handle that by reporting it. I also set a placeholder image when it fails to load.

`<img alt="Image not found" onError="failedToLoadResource" id="something" class="class1 class2">`

This works great. However, just knowing when an image failed to load really isn't enough. I need to be able to identify why it happened. The image is hosted on our server so 404s are unlikely, but not impossible. I don't have access to the client's device and I can't reproduce the issue as described by them.

I've tried looking around but I can't find what I'm looking for...

I'm guessing it might be 404s, some CSP config issue, maybe some internet connection hiccup, whatever. I just want to know what it is, so I can better understand it.

EDIT: Forgot to say the code is in a Cordova app, so there's no log to check.

Comment: So you an do an Ajax call to the image after it fails and get the status code that way.

Comment: Perhaps you should check your server logs on why the image is not being loaded/delivered properly? You can of course perform an AJAX request on the client side and check the HTTP status code returned, but it only tells you the type of error, not why it failed.

Comment: `src being set dynamically` - depending on how this is set, you're most likely to be getting 404s because it's not set correctly.

Comment: Forgot to say the code is in a Cordova app, so there's no log to check. As for the src being set incorrectly, it has worked perfectly for months, but this client's device just didn't want to load their images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client side, you can try to access image by making an ajax call then parsing the response. Easily done using jQuery.

```
var call = $.ajax( "image.img" )
  .fail(function( call, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
```

From the server side, you can check the server logs, search for the correct request and see what happened. If request never came to the server it might be network/routing/firewall problem.

Steps to do this, however, are highly dependent on what is used in the backend.

Comment: Forgot to say the code is in a Cordova app, so there's no log to check. The ajax call is a clever idea that I will definitely implement. However, those might not be the only type of issues that could affect this, correct?

Comment: The fact that front is actually emulated to be native trough browser doesn't mean the back-end doesn't log the requests. Unless you are using images from servers you don't own or have control over. Or are you trying to say you store the images locally on the device? Because it could be a problem of where are you doing so and how.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the server access/error logs. I couldn't see anything that could mean that a resource isn't found, or a request is rejected. I'll accept this as the answer since it has provided a fairly clever solution.

Comment: Hopefully, it helped you get to the bottom of your problem. My logic when I debug problems like this always have a clear line of events that happen internally when you do something. What happens where and test it 1 by 1 till you narrow it down.  Then dig in focusing on that part..